# Live Search Filtering tags td

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

i have problem with my live search the filtering is working but i want is only the `<td>` tags can filter and the `<th>` is not belong.

**this is my html**

```
<input />
 <table class="AvailableGroupLab availGrpLabs avalLabs">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><span>wewe</span>

        </td>
        <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Melvin</span>

        </td>
        <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Marvin</span>

        </td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**and the javascript**

```
function filter(element) {
    var $trs = $('.AvailableGroupLab tr').hide();
    var regexp = new RegExp($(element).val(), 'i');

    var $valid = $trs.filter(function () {
        return regexp.test($(this).find('td:first-child').text())
    }).show();

    $trs.not($valid).hide()
}

$('input').on('keyup change', function () {
    filter(this);
})
```

Comment: Already it is? http://jsfiddle.net/svHfj/

Comment: yeah. but i want is the th is not belong to filtering only the td

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function filter(element) {
var $trs = $('.AvailableGroupLab tr').not(":first").hide(); //don't hide first tr 
var regexp = new RegExp($(element).val(), 'i');

var $valid = $trs.filter(function () {
    return regexp.test($(this).find('td:first-child').text())
}).show();

$trs.not($valid).hide()
}

$('input').on('keyup change', function () {
    filter(this);
})
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/svHfj/1/)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need to select all tr except the first one using `:not(:first-child)`

```
function filter(element) {
    var $trs = $('.AvailableGroupLab tr:not(:first-child)').hide();
    var regexp = new RegExp($(element).val(), 'i');

    var $valid = $trs.filter(function () {
        return regexp.test($(this).find('td:first-child').text())
    }).show();

    $trs.not($valid).hide()
}

$('input').on('keyup change', function () {
    filter(this);
})
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/svHfj/3/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tbody` and `thead`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/svHfj/2/

```
<table class="AvailableGroupLab availGrpLabs avalLabs">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><span>wewe</span>

            </td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>Melvin</span>

            </td>
            <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span>Marvin</span>

            </td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And js

```
function filter(element) {
    var $trs = $('.AvailableGroupLab tbody tr').hide();
    var regexp = new RegExp($(element).val(), 'i');

    var $valid = $trs.filter(function () {
        return regexp.test($(this).find('td:first-child').text())
    }).show();

    $trs.not($valid).hide()
}

$('input').on('keyup change', function () {
    filter(this);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
var $trs = $('.AvailableGroupLab td').hide();
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/svHfj/4/)**

Now it will not filter the Headers.

Answer (score 0):

**[here](http://jsfiddle.net/svHfj/5/)** is the solution to your problem.

use `$('.AvailableGroupLab tr:not(:has(tr)):odd')` instead of `$('.AvailableGroupLab tr')`

```
function filter(element) {
    var $trs = $('.AvailableGroupLab tr:not(:has(tr)):odd').hide();
    var regexp = new RegExp($(element).val(), 'i');

    var $valid = $trs.filter(function () {
        return regexp.test($(this).find('td:first-child').text())
    }).show();

    $trs.not($valid).hide()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply remove th element from your selector

http://jsfiddle.net/svHfj/12/

```
function filter(element) {
    var $trs = $('.AvailableGroupLab tr');

    $trs.each(function() {
        if ( $(this).find('th').length) { // if th remove it
           $trs = $trs.not($(this));          
        }
    });

    $trs.hide();
    var regexp = new RegExp($(element).val(), 'i');

    // also you don't need filter
    $trs.each(function () {        
       if (!regexp.test($(this).find('td:first-child').text())) return;
       $(this).show();
    });
}

$('input').on('keyup change', function () {
    filter(this);
});
```